# Microsoft Graph, Permissions, Create Sharing Link for DriveItem, type:view not working

Tags: hyperlink, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, sharing

The docs here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink claim that you can create a read-only Sharing Link by setting "type" to "view" in the request.

I have done so, and received the expected response with the expected "webUrl" and "type". However, when I visit the webUrl link (for DOCX files), I am taken to an online version of Word that allows me to edit the SharePoint Online file. That is, I appear to have a read-write Sharing Link rather than a read-only Sharing Link.

What am I missing?

Thank you,
James.

Comment: have you tried use account with read only permission to visit the link?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but API access is via user SSO, so read-write permission is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I presume you want to create a Share Link for a SharePoint Online File.

Based on my test, we can create the read-only Sharing Link. When we access to the sharing file with the current user, it will be read-write Sharing Link because the Sharing file is your own file.

And if we use another account to access this file or open the Sharing Link in another browser, it will be read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct, I am trying to create a read-only Share Link for a SharePoint Online file. Ideally, I need the Share Link to be read-only for ALL users--even the owner of the file. Do you know of any way to accomplish that?

Comment: I think this is not possible. The file belong to you, and you own the ownership. You can do everything for it.

Comment: My plan is to see if I can use a service account that has read-only perms to request the Share Link. I will update this thread when I have some results to report (but it may be a while).